# Is there a name for this drop-down anti-pattern?

Tags: navigation, layout, anti-patterns

Recently I have seen a small UI issue in mouse-over drop-downs. Here is an example of such a drop-down (although Bloomberg is not the only offender):

https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2017-08-09/yogurt-liquidity-and-listings

**edit**: Adding marked-up screenshot for historical purposes. The red line is the user's mouse path. Entering the red box will instantly hide the Opinion drop-down.

[image: Bloomberg View - Menu issue]

If you hover over "Opinion" in the top bar, you will be presented with links related to the Opinion section.

The issue: A straight-line path from positions within the Opinion button to some of the links will cross through the "Politics" section, instantly clearing the Opinion options. This means the user has to conciously think about their mouse pathing as they select the link.

Is there a name for this issue? What are the best ways to resolve it?

**edit**: Here is an additional gif displaying the issue, courtesy of [Ben Kamens' blog](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown), which is also [linked by Midas below](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/110935/98732):

[image: Gif demonstrating menu issue]

Comment: I've specifically heard of a fix for this referred to as the "amazon menu hack".

Comment: @jkerian: This problem/solution have been around a lot longer than Amazon has.  I remember reading an article about how Windows 98 handles this, almost 20 years ago.

Comment: Expandable items in dropdowns from the top Menu Bar in Ubuntu suffer from this UX problem, and - even though I'm very much an Ubuntu evangelist/apologist - it drives me *nuts*. Experimenting on my Mac (e.g. using the *Edit->Find* menu in Chrome), it seems that OS X solves the problem by requiring you to keep hovering over the other item for some non-zero minimum time period before the hover takes effect.

Comment: "Is there a name for this drop-down anti-pattern?" Judging by the existing answers, there is no such name.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a screenshot and annotate it for historical purposes: Bloomberg will surely change but we'd like the to keep [ux.se] useful for future readers.

Comment: Solution - Don't use hover for menus. Have it as a click to open for each item. Hovers don't work on touch devices anyway. Nor with keyboard (not easily anyway).

Comment: @msanford: Done. Thank you for the suggestion. @ everyone else, thanks for all the insights!

Comment: Oh man that gif is giving me anxiety

Comment: That GIF is how I expect Macs to work.  You must zig the mouse right to keep the submenu open, then down to the item you want, then click.

Comment: My coworker calls this Super Monkey Ball.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Amazon was founded in 1994.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out 50% of what is wrong with Apple TV

Comment: A very nice read about this issue: http://thomaspark.co/2011/10/making-menus-escapable/

Answer (score 296, accepted):

One suggestion for a name for a solution is from [this great article](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown) is **directional menu aiming**.

It shows how Amazon prevent users from incorrectly selecting an unwanted element while hovering their 'mega-menu', *without using delays*, through detecting the path of the cursor.

> At every position of the cursor you can picture a triangle between the current mouse position and the upper and lower right corners of the dropdown menu. If the next mouse position is within that triangle, the user is probably moving their cursor into the currently displayed submenu. Amazon uses this for a nice effect. As long as the cursor stays within that blue triangle the current submenu will stay open.

[image: Amazon Hover Menu direction]

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. My only suggestion would be to move the left-most point of the triangle to the left-most position of the parent menu option.

Comment: @AlanGeorge Actually you don't need to, you only need to know where the mouse was previously. Once it has moved to the right, you are no longer interested in what's to the *left.* To Midas: this is amazing, I'm going to remember this and suggest this any time I can.

Comment: @Draco18s My line of thinking was, what if the user goes down slightly first before right? It would add a bit more room to move. Just a thought.

Comment: @AlanGeorgeMight be worth having the triangle's tip slightly to the left, but not very far. 5 or 10 pixels, but not all the way to the left hand edge.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks Midas! Is there some kind of library that is capable of accomplishing this or a dev has to write the code?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler [this](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim). it's at the end of article.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice this for *four years*.

Comment: @AlanGeorge I'm skeptical to believe that you can come up with an improvement to a menu that drives billions of dollars of revenue as though it  wasn't already thought of, developed, went through QA, and A/B tested on many thousands of page views.

Comment: Looking at the js, there is a 'tolerance' setting for how forgiving you want it to be.  It's set to 75 by default, so maybe I'm reading its intentions incorrectly?

Comment: @user3067860 you didn't notice it because it's so good. That's the horrible part of UX engineering. If you do your work perfectly, no one will notice.

Comment: @AlanGeorge The size of the menu items helps here - as well as the blue triangle, you can also imagine a box around the entire "Amazon Cloud Drive" menu item which you can also move the mouse around in without the submenu changing

Comment: @NickT You're very much correct, I likely will not. The point of my comments wasn't to fix it, it was to open up a discussion about the possibility of a user going down first. God forbid I have a critical opinion on an expert Q&A site :). I answered my own question when I mocked it up: it felt unnatural to move down first instead of to the right.

Comment: @Kai Good thought! Adds a bit more room.

Comment: Dumb question maybe. Doesn't this fail when you select a parent menu option towards the top, and then the sub menu drop down is larger than the parent menu option and you want to select something near the bottom of the sub menu? Should the 3 points of the triangle not be the parent selected, and the top left and bottom left of the sub menu?

Comment: From the beginning (I think it was 2011 or 2012), the directional triangle was only part of the equation. If the user reverses direction, even within the triangle, the "aiming" is cancelled.

Comment: @plainclothes I haven't looked at the implementation, but that could be achieved by recalculating the triangle after every movement.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Say that to a typographer :-)

Comment: The bottom of the triangle seems a bit overkill for the four items shown .I guess it's a universal triangle, to cover an arbitrary number of items, correct?

Comment: @trlkly to match the height of the elements in the container. you can check for yourself on Amazon

Answer (score 97):

**The issue you're talking about is sometimes referred to as a "[narrow mouse corridor](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/)".** Having a narrow mouse corridor can result in users becoming frustrated by the lack of [user control](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/timing-exposing-content/).

An alternative to Amazon's triangle approach (which was originally done by [Bruze Tognazzini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Tognazzini) in 1986 with Apple) is to use [little boxes to extend the corridor](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/). One advantage of this particular implementation is that it's pure CSS (pseudo-elements) so it removes the [dependency on jQuery](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim) (or vanilla JS).

[image: Image from: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/]

(Image from: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/)

Comment: What jQuery dependency? Do you mean JavaScript?

Comment: @Segfault It's a reference to [jQuery-menu-aim](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim) which is mentioned at the bottom of the article linked by Midas.

Comment: Wouldn't this act as if I were hovering above 'your settings' if I was permanently hovering the left side of 'help'?

Comment: So the red squares belong to "Your Settings"?

Comment: jQuery is not a panacea. You can so this with vanilla JS in less than 30 LoC.

Comment: @EdmundReed Yes, it would. The article states that the "slight danger is that you can cover up a decent amount of adjacent menu items, which could mean a user hovering over a legit menu item and not being able to click it. I imagine in a lot of cases they just move the mouse a little and it works, but it's definitely a balancing act between too small and too big."  However, one commenter suggested that you could use the (un)hover technique he talks about in combination with the red boxes to prevent this issue.

Comment: @problemofficer Yes, please see the linked article for more details.

Comment: @marstato This can certainly be implemented in vanilla JS, but I was referencing the jQuery plugin that Ben Kamens created (the author of the article listed in the accepted answer). I've modified my post to clarify this, thanks.

Answer (score 36):

Where I work, we call that a "death-star trench menu".
I"m pretty sure we didn't invent that name, but I can't find the book it's from.

Comment: Did a Google search for it - doesn't seem to used by anyone outside your company.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46712)

Comment: @Mayo: The primary question I see is, "Is there a name for this?"  So it looks to me like this is an answer to the question.

Comment: As someone who used to bulls-eye womp rats, I don't have any difficulty with these menus.  But I like this answer!

Comment: +1 for irrational Star Wars reference. Not much use as an answer, but we need some comic relief around here!

Answer (score 9):

From a programer perspective, I would suggest a hover intent function (delaying the environment reaction by some 300ms. This isn't too visible and would reduce the risk of accidental closing/opening of menus). Although you may find that the 300ms would add up in more complex trees of menus and sub-menus..

Comment: I would imagine there is a reason the "programmer perspective" is not up-voted.  But this is why I (also a programmer) highly value the input of a dedicated UX designer, because the quickest/easiest/most intuitive solution to program is ultimately solving the problem of programming before the problem of UX.

Comment: This seems like a lot less effort than the Amazon solution, and it's my usual recommendation in projects I work on. The drawback is that hover delay slows down the user as they're using the nav menu. Maybe 300ms is the sweet spot where the menu still feels snappy. I'd want to try a few different delays and see how they feel.

Answer (score 5):

The name I use for this pattern is **hover tunnel**.

Hover tunnels have long been recognized as problematic: http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/

> One of the worst things about hover menus is that they force users to move their mouse through hover tunnels. Hover tunnels are passages that users have to move their mouse through to click an item. Older users who are less tech-savvy will often have trouble doing this. Even tech-savvy users can find it annoying that they have to move their mouse in a confined path.

**I suspect the 'anti-pattern' is just a side effect** of the hover tunnel collapsing because, altogether, it would not be a reliable way to direct users to ads or other content.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not a name for this pattern.

Its just a hover menu, hover menus are trash when it comes to UX. Even me, an experienced internet user has problems navigating through such menus and in 9 out of 10 times i get mad when i have to use a hover menu.

One thing to make such menus a bit more user friendly is for example to set a small delay when the users navigates out of the table so the menu is not closing immediately but has like 1-1.5s delay so the user has the chance to move the mouse back while in his normal flow.

Comment: 1-1.5s sounds way too slow

Comment: I can get behind this.  There's nothing more infuriating than a site that uses hover menus.  If I wanted it to drop down/pop out I would have clicked on it.  Delay might be a bit long, but I've seen that tactic used to help mitigate the horror of hover menus.

Comment: Hover menus are even more obnoxious than infinite scrolling.

Comment: @Bergi It does *sound* slow, but it's the same in Windows (of course, it can be dismissed immediately by clicking). In Windows, the menu also doesn't disappear when you leave it. The sub-menus are hover-based, but since the "main" menu wasn't, it's clear that it only disappears on a click (or key-press). Too bad that this is impossible now on the web, since many sites use the "main menu buttons" as both drop-downs and links on their own, not to mention that the mouse control still isn't quite good enough for that. And then they do the same thing again for the sub-menus, argh.

Comment: @Luaan Ah, maybe I misunderstood it at first. A long(ish) timeout for *closing* the pop-out menu might be fine, I thought the 1-1.5s were proposed as a delay for *switching* between the menu options to prevent the mouse corridor problem.

Comment: @Bergi I meant the delay before the hover menu is closing after moving the mouse outside of that area. I often find it really annoying if i browse a multi-level hover menu and accidentally hover outside and the whole menu collapses.

Comment: @PectoralisMajor Yes, that's a problem, but imo not the problem that this question is about: "*A straight-line path from positions within the Opinion button to some of the links will cross through the "Politics" section, instantly clearing the Opinion options.*"